# Java/Groovy Rails Database Migrations

Tags: java, ruby-on-rails, groovy, migration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Migrations for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131020/migrations-for-java)

Is there a tool in the Java/Groovy world that lets me manage database changes similar to the way that Rails Database Migrations work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131020/migrations-for-java

Answer (score 1):

If you dont mind using the rails way db schema just use rails migrations for your project.

I have a PHP project and I setup a bare rails project with migrations for it.

Works great.

Answer (score 0):

In the Grails world, you can use the [Autobase plugin](http://www.grails.org/plugin/autobase).  If that is nonsensical for your project, you can just use the tool that it is based off of, [Liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/manual/home).  Both are a nice set of idiomatic Java/Grails tools.

Answer (score 0):

I blogged about database migrations for java recently [here](http://karussell.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/simple-database-migration-in-java/).

Comment: Great blog post karussel!   You showed me migrate4j!!

Comment: Glad that I could help you :-)