# SSDT Equivalent for Oracle Database

Tags: java, oracle, sql-server-data-tools, schema-migration

In SSDT there is a mechanism for managing DDL changes, for instance a new column or a change to a data type. Instead of putting an 'Alter Table' statement into the database project, instead we edit that original 'Create Table' statement which focuses on the final state that includes the new column. It detects the difference between older and new script and creates necessary 'Alter Table' script to use for deployment.

Is there any equivalent strategy to achieve the same in Oracle Database as I am using J2EE technologies and Eclipse IDE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it is not I am afraid, SSDT is a free tool developed by Microsoft to help SQL Server deployments. I would think it extremely unlikely that Microsoft would ever allow let alone help deployments to Oracle - it is a new Microsoft sure but some things will never change!

The best alternative is to use JetBrains datagrip  as an IDE and flyway as a deployment tool:

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/oracle

https://www.jetbrains.com/datagrip/

In my opinion Microsoft has created the best development environment of ANY RDBMS and throw in the redgate suite of tools and it makes the tooling a real differentiator.

Ed

Answer (score 1):

It's not built into the IDE like SSDT is, but Redgate [has comparison tools for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/schema-compare-for-oracle/) that use the same methodology as SSDT Database Projects.

This can be used in conjunction with [Redgate Source Control for Oracle](http://www.red-gate.com/products/oracle-development/source-control-for-oracle/), which maintains a schema model in your chosen VCS.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is ["Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio"](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/visual-studio/overview/index.html) .

I haven't looked at this for 5+ years but it used to do some of the same things that the old Visual Studio Database Tools (datadude/dbproj/other names) did back then.

Comment: I don't have Visual Studio. I want to achieve the same with any freeware tools as I am using Eclipse. I used to do the same in Visual Studio in my previous organization. But now in my current organization we are using Eclipse as everything is open source and free.

Comment: There are some suggestions for db migration tools for java in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/3867045/1100346 , but there's not much "IDE experience" with any of them. TL;DR: flyway or liquibase